# Lookup filter to display Contacts related to selected Account

Tags: lookup, lookup-filter

I want to apply a lookup filter on Quote object on the lookup field "Contact". The filter should be such the Contact lookup dialogue box should only display the Contacts related to the Account mentioned in that Quote. What criteria should I apply?

Answer (score 1):

I tried to implement this, but could not able to find a straight solution.

You can try below solution.

1. Create a new Lookup field (Account) on Quote object.
2. Then apply a lookup filter criteria on Contact field as below,
   [image]
3. Once you select a Account lookup, the contact field will display only those contacts which are related to selected Account.
4. The only overhead here is, user needs to select extra Account field and then user will select the associated Contact.

Comment: am also facing same issue, in my condition am not fetching related contact. why means in sandbox having 15000 accounts/person contacts. in this bulk of contact records time how can i fetch my related contact

Answer (score 0):

Inside the Lookup Filter apply this Filter Criteria

"Lookup Contacts: Account ID EQUALS  Quote: Account ID"

Comment: Thanks. But the Account ID field is not showing in the list of fields. Neither it is being routed from Opportunity ID. I also tried creating a formula field which will capture the Account Name/ID however this formula field is also not showing in the list of fields in filter criteria option. Tried achieving this with workflow but that didn't worked either. Salesforce has set some security which is blocking to use the Account ID field in lookup filter criteria.